# Magento add banner to a custom phtml

Tags: php, mysql, html, magento, magento-1.6

i'm new to magento, I'd like to add a banner that I can handle using the CMS so I don't need to edit the HTML directly.

Actually I'm using a Static Block, so I can edit it and it shows up inside the page.
I've read online some example using a widget, but it's not clear to me what is the advantage of a widget over a simple static block. By the way, the widget doesn't show up inside the page, as a result of a long googling it seems that may depend on the custom theme that doesn't support widgets...

How can I include a widget inside the page and/or re-enable the opportunity to choose where to place it inside the CMS?

What is the advantage of a widget over a simple static block?

I'm working on a magento 1.6

Comment: Is there anything you want to do with setting the logo that can't be done in the admin's Design Configuration? Your question also went from changing the logo to how to include a widget. If all you need to do is change the logo, you don't need a widget.

Comment: Sorry, how did I mention the logo? I need to add a banner to promote products, but since it will be a frequent change I want to handle it inside the CMS instead of editing the phtml file.

Comment: Okay, I assumed the banner was the logo image, as some of people call the header image of their website a banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a banner or banner slideshow markup in your pages you may create a static block with the required html.

Then add it to any pages using a layout update.  I prefer to use the `app\design\frontend\default\absolute\layout\local.xml`.  If you haven't got it already, create this file then put the below xml in it.

Here the id of your static block is assumed as `custm_slideshow`.  The below snippet is specific for the home page.  But if you want to show it in all the pages, instead of `<cms_index_index></<cms_index_index>` use `<default></default>`.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="custom.slideshow">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>custom_slideshow</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

If you wanted to read more about widgets [here is a good one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/introducing-magento-widgets/), in case you missed it.

Comment: maybe you can also help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431767/magento-customize-catalogsearch-result-html ?