# Magento customize catalogsearch result html

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.6

I'd like to customize the layout for the result page of CatalogSearch.

I'd like to remove the pagination and all other tools on the page and show a much simpler page since we only have few products. Then I need to change how results are displayed to customize the size of images and add a rollover on images.

How can I do that?
By looking at the source code it calls `$this->getProductListHtml()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to determine which template files to edit, is to enable the "Template Path Hints" in your Magento Configuration.

To do this, do the following:

1. In your Magento Admin, go to **System > Configuration > Developer**
2. On the top left under **Current Configuration Scope**, select **Main Website** (or the name of the site you are trying to modify.)
3. Now on the right, set **Template Path Hints** to **Yes** and click **Save Config**
4. Go back to your frontend.  Each section will now display the exact template you need to modify.  *NOTE: You should always copy the default template files to your own template directory, instead of modifying Magento's core theme.*

---

Alternately, you can target each page in Magento using CSS.  Magento assigns a unique class to each page's `<body>` tag

In your case, the Catalog Search Results page has a body class of **catalogsearch-result-index**.  If you want to hide the toolbar on that page, you can add the following to your template's style.css file:

```
.catalogsearch-result-index .toolbar {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I edit the way it display records? I want to customize it, and I'm not able to find the right phtml (the one I tried [1] calls some internal method). [1] frontend/default/default/template/magiczoom/list.phtml

Comment: I found it! It's `catalog/product/list.phtml`